# How do I reschedule a quartz trigger?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-3.5, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have used quartz scheduling and I am getting the following exception every time I go to edit a schedule that is not a one time schedule. (that is its weekly or hourly.

```
2015-04-08 08:34:00.0464[SubscriptionService] JobScheduler Exception :   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present  in the dictionary.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at ReportingService.ReportEngine.GetParameterProperty(String param, Dictionary`2 dataset)
   at ReportingService.ProgrammabilityManager..ctor(IEnumerable`1 procs, Dictionary`2 list, CallType callType, ReportEngine engine)
   at ReportingService.ReportEngine.GetReportData(IEnumerable`1 parameter, IEnumerable`1 proc, IEnumerable`1 join, IEnumerable`1 field)
   at ReportingService.ReportEngine.ProcessReportData(String section, String name, String[] parameters)
   at ReportingService.ReportEngine.GetParameterizedReport(String section, String name, String format, String[] parameters)
   at Zone24x7.MX4Broker.Services.ScheduledJobExecuter.RetrieveScheduledJob(String id)
   at Zone24x7.MX4Broker.Services.Job.LongRunningJob(Object obj)
```

But every time the edit button is clicked in my application,  I am creating a new trigger and new job. Does this have something to do with editing a schedule? Is this because of not using RescheduleJob method? Please advice.

Below is my trigger and job creation code:

```
 IJobDetail _JobOne = JobBuilder.Create<Job>()
                    .WithIdentity(guid.ToString() + "*" + id)
                    .Build();

 ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .ForJob(_JobOne)
                            .WithIdentity(guid.ToString() + "*" + id,"minuteWithEnd")
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                            .WithIntervalInMinutes(minutes)
                            .RepeatForever())
                            .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(StartHour, StartMinute, StartSeconds, StartDate, StartMonth, StartYear))
                            .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0,0,0,EndDay,EndMonth,EndYear))
                            .Build();
```

And below is my job class:

```
 public class Job : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        NLog.Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("[SubscriptionService]");

        SubscriptionServiceDAL dal = new SubscriptionServiceDAL();

        string[] keys = context.JobDetail.Key.ToString().Split('.');

        string JobKey = keys[1].ToString();

        foreach (string s in keys)
            logger.Debug("key is: " + s+"\n");

        logger.Debug(JobKey);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(LongRunningJob, JobKey);

    }

    public void LongRunningJob(object obj)
    {
        string id = obj.ToString().Split('*')[1];

        NLog.Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("[SubscriptionService]");

        SubscriptionServiceDAL dal = new SubscriptionServiceDAL();

        logger.Debug("------------------- Job" + obj.ToString() + " Executed ---------------------");

        try
        {
            logger.Debug("ID in Long Running Job is: " + id);
            dal.UpdateLastExecuteDateTime(id);
            logger.Debug("came after  dal.UpdateLastExecuteDateTime ");
            ScheduledJobExecuter exec = new ScheduledJobExecuter();

            exec.RetrieveScheduledJob(id);

            logger.Debug("exec.RetrieveScheduledJob ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Debug(" JobScheduler Exception : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're creating new trigger and job?

Comment: @CircularReferenceI have added the code. Please advice

Comment: I can see how you are creating your job and trigger, but how are you actually scheduling them?